# IAM/S3 policy error with streaming multipart upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm trying to upload a PostgreSQL backup to s3 using the `-` (stdin) source for aws-cli `s3 cp` with ideally, a write-only policy (backup user should be able to write, but not delete, deletion is handled with a bucket policy that rotates out files to infrequently (IA) accessed storage, eventually to glacier, and after a while, finally deletes them)

There's an error, however:

```
upload failed: ./- to s3://bucket-name/postgresql/dbname_2017-06-23T20:26:39+0000.sqlc
A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation: Access Denied
Cleaning up. Please wait...
```

The command I'm running is:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=••• AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=••• AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1 /usr/bin/pg_dump --username username -p 6432 -Fc dbname | /usr/bin/aws s3 cp --sse=aws:kms - s3://bucket-name/postgresql/dbname_$(date --iso-8601=s).sqlc
```

The credentials used have one and only one policy attached:

`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1498224672102",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListObjects",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}`

I can't find documented anywhere the correct incantations to make `CreateMultipartUpload` work, even the `--debug` trace log doesn't really help, and I can't find anything suitable in the AWS docs.

```
2017-06-23 20:03:20,766 - Thread-5 - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Sending http request: <PreparedRequest [POST]>
2017-06-23 20:03:20,767 - Thread-5 - botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - INFO - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
2017-06-23 20:03:20,872 - Thread-5 - botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - "POST /bucket-name/postgresql/dbname_2017-06-23T20%3A03%3A18%2B0000.sqlc?uploads HTTP/1.1" 403 None
2017-06-23 20:03:20,873 - Thread-5 - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response headers: {'x-amz-id-2': 'Qig+LfMtw3WPp+R3I7A3XUQQjlEQRHCuEsNWbgFnpPhglIlRkFp2aQRTpPk4ZF+kyTuBHQG2R58=', 'server': 'AmazonS3', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'x-amz-request-id': '7FC2F6D75773CD03', 'date': 'Fri, 23 Jun 2017 20:03:20 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/xml'}
2017-06-23 20:03:20,873 - Thread-5 - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response body:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>7FC2F6D75773CD03</RequestId><HostId>Qig+LfMtw3WPp+R3I7A3XUQQjlEQRHCuEsNWbgFnpPhglIlRkFp2aQRTpPk4ZF+kyTuBHQG2R58=</HostId></Error>
2017-06-23 20:03:20,873 - Thread-5 - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event needs-retry.s3.CreateMultipartUpload: calling handler <botocore.retryhandler.RetryHandler object at 0x289abd0>
2017-06-23 20:03:20,873 - Thread-5 - botocore.retryhandler - DEBUG - No retry needed.
2017-06-23 20:03:20,874 - Thread-5 - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event after-call.s3.CreateMultipartUpload: calling handler <function enhance_error_msg at 0x21e3668>
2017-06-23 20:03:20,874 - Thread-5 - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event after-call.s3.CreateMultipartUpload: calling handler <awscli.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x2250d10>
2017-06-23 20:03:20,874 - Thread-5 - awscli.errorhandler - DEBUG - HTTP Response Code: 403
2017-06-23 20:03:20,874 - Thread-5 - awscli.customizations.s3.tasks - DEBUG - Error trying to create multipart upload: A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation: Access Denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/customizations/s3/tasks.py", line 465, in __call__
    upload_id = self.filename.create_multipart_upload()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/customizations/s3/fileinfo.py", line 354, in create_multipart_upload
    response_data = self.client.create_multipart_upload(**params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 310, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 403, in _make_api_call
    model=operation_model, context=request_context
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 226, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 209, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/errorhandler.py", line 70, in __call__
    http_status_code=http_response.status_code)
ClientError: A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation: Access Denied
2017-06-23 20:03:20,875 - Thread-5 - awscli.customizations.s3.executor - DEBUG - Error calling task: A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation: Access Denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/customizations/s3/executor.py", line 226, in run
    function()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/customizations/s3/tasks.py", line 477, in __call__
    raise e
ClientError: A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation: Access Denied
2017-06-23 20:03:20,875 - Thread-3 - awscli.customizations.s3.executor - DEBUG - Received print task: PrintTask(message=u'upload failed: ./- to s3://bucket-name/postgresql/dbname_2017-06-23T20:03:18+0000.sqlc\nA client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation: Access Denied', error=True, total_parts=None, warning=None)
```

**Can anyone help with naming the correct policy actions to make this work?**

Comment: Check the bucket for a policy.  A matching deny rule in any applicable policy always overrules any matching allow rule.

Comment: Good idea, thanks - the bucket has no policy of it's own. Back to the drawing board.